# Tomcat 9 on Debian won't run

Tags: java, tomcat

I have Tomcat 9 installed on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ using the OS Raspbian. When I run startup.sh, I get this output and then it terminates:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat9
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat9
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR:   /opt/tomcat9/temp
Using JRE_HOME:   /usr
Using CLASSPATH:   /opt/tomcat9/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat9/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

And then it immediately ends without anything else. Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startup.sh` actually starts `catalina.sh` in the background.

To see the actual error in your current console, you can use:

```
catalina.sh run
```

Usually the error is an occupied port (which can be configured in `conf/server.xml`), or a misconfiguration of a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat with JRE_HOME pointing to `/usr` usually is wrong.

As it uses `/etc/sudoers` settings (for Tomcat users). 
One should add to `/etc/sudoers` a line with

```
Defaults    env_keep += "JAVA_HOME JRE_HOME"
```